# Why is my program's core dump always zero bytes, when run on an NTFS partition mounted in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, crash, crash-dumps, coredump

I'm trying to get a usable core dump from code that I am writing.  My source is on a NTFS partition that I share between Windows and Linux OSes.  I'm doing the development under Linux and have set `ulimit -c unlimited` in my bash shell.  When I execute the code in my project directory on the NTFS partition, and purposely cause a SIGSEGV or SIGABRT, the system writes a core dump file of zero bytes.

If I execute the binary in my home directory (an ext4 partition), the core dump is generated fine. I've had a look at the [man page for core](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/core.5.html), which gives a list of various circumstances in which a core dump file is not produced. However, I don't think it's a permissions issue as all the files and directories on that partition have full rights (`chmod 777`).

Any help or thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Did you use the kernel ntfs or userspace ntfs-3g to mount the partition?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should check the this file (/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

The directory where the application sits is a mount point to another linux machine. The core file can't be written to a mounted drive but must be written to the local drive.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Linux/Q_23677186.html

You can create ram disk and put the core dump on the ram disk.

Comment: Please do not link to experts-exchange.com since we need to be registered to see the answer. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I'm not going to dispute the accuracy of your answer, but it unfortunately doesn't answer the question. The OP isn't asking _whether_ a core file can be written; they are asking _why_ it can't. Possibly the answer to this is contained in the link you posted, but I don't have a membership to experts-exchange so I can't see it (as @j0k pointed out)

Answer (score 0):

Has your ntfs partition enough free space to generate the core dump ?
Is your ntfs partition mounted with read/write rights (not only read) ?

Comment: Yes, and yes. Approx. 48GB of space free, partition is mounted rw: `/dev/sda5 on /mnt/data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096)`.